# Converting image to base64 in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, base64, beanshell

I'm new to Jmeter and need some guide. I'm trying to read in a lot images from a directory and need to convert each picture to base64 in Jmeter. If I understand correct, in the HTTP request I can use __FileToString. However, I need convert it first and then pass to the request.
I have tried using ForController and converting as described on the Internet with BeanShell Sampler, but the image comes out corrupted. Could you please direct me how to do it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard [Groovy is the new black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/), moreover [you should not be using Beanshell since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

So you can convert an image into its Base64 representation using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/image.png').bytes.encodeBase64().toString(),)}
```